# using the dbset of Inherited class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dbset

Lets say I have a class **Foods**

```
public class FoodsContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
   public DbSet<Consumer> Consumers {get; set;}
}
```

and there is class **Fruits**

```
public class FruitsContext: FoodsContext
{
   public DbSet<Price> Prices {get; set;}
}
```

then in my repository
Lets say I have

```
public class SampleRepository
{
   private readonly FruitsContext _dbFruits = new FruitsContext();

   public void foo()
   {
      _dbFruits.Prices.doanything;
      //how can i use Consumers table that has been set in Foods class
   }
}
```

In my repository class I want to access values from **Consumers** table, without creating an instance of **Food** class. How can I do that?

I had seen this in some project but I don't quite remember it now. Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do

```
public void foo()
{
  _dbFruits.Prices.doanything;
  //how can i use Consumers table that has been set in Foods class
  _dbFruits.Set<Consumer>.doanything;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a DbContext method. Another base class.

Comment: But do review your design and maybe copy something that was worked out more. And UnitOfWork usually owns 1 or more Repositories, it's not their base class.

Comment: actually my design is much more complex, i just wanted to show the basic random class here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like plain inheritance to me:

```
public void foo()
{
  _dbFruits.Prices.doanything;
  //how can i use Consumers table that has been set in Foods class
  _dbFruits.Consumers.doanything;  // this should work
}
```

Comment: this could work but i have posted an answer which also worked